# What are the algorithms that could be represented mathematically as an equation?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

So if I have an algorithm let's say "if you have a number n every time the algorithm runs the number triples and becomes greater by 5. As I understand I would write such equation as 3n+5 and then for every greater term I would use a composition of functions.

The question is what are other algorithms besides "increased x times and became greater by y" that can be represented mathematically AS AN EQUATION?

I am asking this because I cannot think of any other algorithms that could be expressed as an equation.

Comment: This is far too broad.

Comment: @lulu I personally disagree; it is super broad of course, but (i) it arguably has a snappy answer ("Turing machines") and (ii) it's *so* natural a question to ask, and such a good one to be bothered by, that I think this is a situation where we should be more-than-usually tolerant of excessive breadth.

Comment: I would say every algorithm is mathematical.  Do you mean to ask "which algorithms can be represented by an elementary closed formula?"

Comment: Algorithms have mathematical properties (characteristics we can reason about, such as complexity and termination), but it's a stretch to speak about which algorithms "can be represented mathematically".  One would need a way to represent the universe of algorithms formally ("mathematically") in order to discuss whether they are so.  The [Church-Turing Thesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis) says functions of the natural numbers that are *effectively computable* are the same as the ones [computable by a Turing machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine).

Comment: I was basically asking if it was possible to express any other algorithms as an equation

Answer (score 2):

There is of course a huge ambiguity around what "mathematically-representable algorithm" means. For example, are we allowed to include steps like "if the twin prime conjecture is true, then [stuff]"?

However, there is a natural formal notion here: that of the [**computable** (or **recursive**) **functions**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_function). There are many equivalent formal definitions of these, with arguably the most intuitively compelling one being [Turing machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine), and it is generally accepted that these constitute those functions which have "genuine" algorithms (this statement is called [Church's thesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis), or in more recent literature the Church-Turing thesis).

There are also interesting more restricted notions of computation. For example, in general it's not possible to tell, algorithmically, whether a computable function [is defined on a given input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem); maybe we want to restrict attention to algorithms which "clearly" always halt. Historically the first formal notion of computation (that I'm aware of, anyways) is [**primitive recursion**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function), which is much more restricted. There is in general a rich universe of such "subrecursion" notions *(and I have to at this point plug one of my mathematical heroes, [Rozsa Peter](https://www.sdsc.edu/ScienceWomen/peter.html), who is not nearly as well-known as she should be)*; theoretical computer science (in particular, *complexity theory*) tends to study ones much weaker than primitive recursion (e.g. [P, NP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem), EXP, ...), but there are also ones much stronger than primitive recursion.

---

It's worth noting that all of the above is focusing on algorithms/functions on the **natural numbers** *(or equivalent domains, like integers, rationals, finite binary strings, ...)*.  Going beyond this - even to just *real* numbers - introduces genuine difficulties, and one should thoroughly understand the basic theory of computation on $\mathbb{N}$ before going further. That said, the "natural next step" is [computable analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_analysis) in its various flavors.